# unable to access variable declared in ksh script to csh script using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh, csh

I am unable to access variable declared in a KornShell (ksh) script from another c shell script for example,

```
vi script.ksh
set MyUser=root
set MyPassword=shroot
exit

vi script.csh
. /script1.ksh
echo $MyUser
echo $MyPassword
exit
```

The problem involved here is its unable to access the variable MyUser and MyPassword from the script1 .ksh in script2.csh.

Can you please suggest in this case?

Comment: you can't 'source' a script in one shell and have it execute cmds with the syntax of another shell. Your example is a big mix-up between the syntax's of the 2 shells. `source envFile` is really the best you can do in `csh`. and some issue in ksh, `. envFile.ksh`, you can't use csh `set var = value` (note the spaces) in `ksh`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The `ksh` script is not doing what you think it is doing when used by `ksh`; it sets `$1` first to `MyUser=root` and then `MyPassword=shroot`.

However, when you source it from your C shell script, because the syntax is compatible with C shell (checked with `tcsh`), you would set the two variables.  If you sourced the script from a Bourne-shell derivative, the `exit` at the end of the `ksh` script would cause the shell to exit; it does not seem to cause the C shell to `exit`.

So, what you've got is a weird hybrid.  Normally, you stick to one language and use it exclusively.  Where you need to use another shell, you can do so, but you simply run the script written for the other shell.  You can communicate to the other script with environment variables.  You don't normally try writing sourceable code that can be used by both C shell and Bourne-shell derivatives; there is too much syntax that is different.